# CUDA array/vector delete

Tags: arrays, vector, cuda

I am new to CUDA and am trying to write my own kernel.

On the CPU side, I have a series of vectors containing ints (one vector/GPU thread).

I want each of the GPU threads to remove some of the elements from its vector that I will then copy back to the host.  On the CPU side the comparable operation would be:

```
vector.erase(element_number);
```

My understanding is that stl type vectors are not supported on the GPU and I really can't use Thrust (because I am using my own kernel).

However, I could convert the CPU vectors to arrays (including data on the number of elements) and then copy the arrays to the GPU. Then, If I  identified an element to be deleted, I could shift all the elements below up and decrement the total number of elements.

Before I recreate the wheel and write that, my question is: is there some CUDA supported operation that already does this?

Comment: There is nothing built into CUDA that provides vector manipulation or array manipulation like that.  Although such operations seem convenient to the programmer, they are not particularly high performance, so you might want to come up with a different scheme of data management that doesn't require that sort of insert/delete operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You'd have to write your own vector class in the way you describe.

If you don't care about the order of the elements in the vector, you can implement the erase operation by swapping the element to be erased with the last element in the vector, and then decrementing the size, instead of moving everything.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I understand that this is not making the best use of the GPU.  The underlying algorithm forces you to do this part sequentially.  Nevertheless, because hundreds/thousands of threads will run simultaneously, this should still be dramatically faster than the CPU version.  The vectors here correspond to OpenCV contour points Thus, you need to preserve the vector order to maintain contour integrity.

Comment: There are still plenty of ways to avoid the painful process of moving vector elements one-by-one like this.  A simple indirection scheme could work.  And if it occasionally made sense, you could restore vector order with gather methods.  Depending on your actual use case, these could be a lot more efficient than just blindly using vector insert/delete.

Comment: Is there a particular indirection scheme you are thinking of?  Given that the elements are just ints, very simple ones will likely not work because the time saved copying just gets transferred to time spent doing element accesses (because you have to calculate position).  To give a sense, these vectors might have 2,000 elements to start out but then get reduced to 20 total.  The dumb scheme I am using starts out slow but then speeds up  as elements are removed.